# changing jvm heap size - jgrasp

Tags: java, jvm, heap-memory, jgrasp

I know how to increase java heap size on command line using flag -Xmx, I need to run my program in jgrasp, how do I increase the heap size for my program in that IDE?

> System.out.println("---->"+Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory());

prints ---->66650112

on adding flag -Xmx256m

the heap size still print the same number

Answer (score 2):

Even when you pass `-Xmx256m`, it doesn't mean that the JVM is going to allocate that amount right away.  `-Xmx` specifies the *max* heap.  The JVM will wait to allocate more heap up until that limit as it sees fit.  If you want to specify the *min* heap and make sure you reach the limit right away, use `-Xms256m`.

Comment: even after setting -Xms256m I am still getting the same amount of max memory printed out 66650112 :S

Answer (score 0):

For increasing the memory of IDE itself, you will have to add those arguments to jgrasp_portable.bat or winconfig_portable.bat

However from your question it seems, you want to add memory to program running inside the IDE. For that, right click on project in jgrasp IDE, go to Compiler settings -  this will open a small popup window in which choose compiler tab. There you have subtabs, choose "Flags/Args/Main", here you can add JVM heap sizes. As suggest in previous answer if you need more memory right on startup, it's better to mark -Xms and -Xmx both in appropriate size. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Do what Vishal said, and set "FLAGS2" for "Run" and for "Debug". "FLAGS" will add to your program arguments instead. You can do this at the workspace, project, or file level depending on your needs.

Also, the I/O pane will show the command sent, so you can verify the flags there. If you turn on "Settings" -> "Verbose Messages" it will show the exact command, generally including the path to the Java executable.

For jGRASP itself, use "Settings" -> "jGRASP Startup Settings" on Windows or Mac. jgrasp_portable.bat only applies if you are running jGRASP in portable mode (usually installed on a USB stick).